# Why Link to query a db does not work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page which displays links, so when I click on that link , it should take me to another page and queries the database so that I can only see the information of that particular link . But now it gives me a problem it it’s the same code I use in other programs . I have been trying to figure this out for almost 2hours . Please below is the code anybody who can help you are welcome .

```
First piece of code or page 
<?php 
$selector1 =("SELECT job_id, job_title, job_description, 
job_category, wantORoffering, address, cell, email, date_registered, 
user_id from h2s_job ORDER BY date_registered DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
$result_selector=$con->prepare($selector1);
$result_selector->execute();
while($row = $result_selector->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
#substring 
$job_description = $row['job_description'];
$job_description  = wordwrap($job_description , 200);
$job_description  = explode("\n", $job_description );
$job_description  = $job_description [0] . '...';
#substring 
echo '<a href="jobdetails.php?job_id=$job_id"><div id="record" id ="record-">
<strong class="pic"><img src="images/nopic.png" ></strong>
<strong class="job_title"><h4>',$row['job_title'],'</h4></strong></br>
 <strong class ="desc"><p>',$job_description,'</p></strong></br>
  <strong class="contact"><p>',$row['cell'],'</strong></br>
<strong class="time"><p>',$row['date_registered'],'</strong></br>
</div></a>';
}?>



Second page 


<?php 

$selector =("SELECT  job_title, job_description, 
job_category, wantORoffering, address, cell, email, date_registered, 
user_id FROM  h2s_job WHERE job_id =".$_GET['job_id']);
$result_selector=$con->prepare($selector);
$result_selector->execute();
while($row = $result_selector->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
#substring 
$job_description = $row['job_description'];
echo '<div id="record" id ="record-">
<strong class="pic"><img src="images/nopic.png" ></strong>
<strong class="job_title"><h4>',$row['job_title'],'</h4></strong></br>
 <strong class ="desc"><p>',$job_description,'</p></strong></br>
  <strong class="contact"><p>',$row['cell'],'</strong></br>
<strong class="time"><p>',$row['date_registered'],'</strong></br>
</div></a>';
}
?>
```

The error I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '$job_id' in 'where clause'' in C:\wamp\www\houseCurrent\jobdetails.php:98 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\houseCurrent\jobdetails.php(98): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\houseCurrent\jobdetails.php on line 98
```

Comment: look at using placeholders for your variables e.g. `job_id=:job_id` then binding the $job_id variable to the :job_id placeholder http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: `<a href="jobdetails.php?job_id=$job_id` <- Where are you storing some data into the `$job_id`?

Comment: Is the correct id passed in url?

Comment: the echo statement uses commas, use `.` instead and split off $job_id too `".$job_id."`

Comment: Am I being thick or is there no sql statement with a $job_id in a WHERE clause of the code posted here?

Comment: @humphrey WHERE?? I found job_id and $_GET['job_id'] and echo '..$job_id..'; BUT nowhere in an SQL

Comment: I manged to fix it by using ' . $job_id . ' and $job_id = $row['job_id'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probability you forget to add `$job_id = $row['job_id'];` at first `while`

Comment: @humphrey , regardless of working or not, is it a typo? or then, where did you set $job_id?

Comment: Yes by the end of the day it worked and your Line played a big role thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$job_id doesn't seem to be defined and the link created with the echo-statement isn't what you want (I expect...) Option1 doesn't assign job_id the actual value (it assigns string '$job_id').

Option2 does the trick and assigns job_id to value 5.

```
<?php
$job_id = 5; //example

//OPTION 1 This would output to html => jobdetails.php?job_id=$job_id
echo '<a href="jobdetails.php?job_id=$job_id">test</a>';

//OPTION 2 This would output to html => jobdetails.php?job_id=5
echo '<a href="jobdetails.php?job_id=' . $job_id . '">test</a>';
?>
```

You could change... (option 1)

```
echo '<a href="jobdetails.php?job_id=$job_id"><div id="record" id ="record-">
<strong class="pic"><img src="images/nopic.png" ></strong>
<strong class="job_title"><h4>',$row['job_title'],'</h4></strong></br>
 <strong class ="desc"><p>',$job_description,'</p></strong></br>
  <strong class="contact"><p>',$row['cell'],'</strong></br>
<strong class="time"><p>',$row['date_registered'],'</strong></br>
</div></a>';
```

to (option 2)

```
echo '<a href="jobdetails.php?job_id=' . $job_id . '"><div id="record" id ="record-">
<strong class="pic"><img src="images/nopic.png" ></strong>
<strong class="job_title"><h4>' . $row['job_title'] . '</h4></strong></br>
 <strong class ="desc"><p>' . $job_description . '</p></strong></br>
  <strong class="contact"><p>' . $row['cell'] . '</strong></br>
<strong class="time"><p>' . $row['date_registered'] . '</strong></br>
</div></a>';
```

Commas has been replaced with periods because . is used for concatenation of strings.

Comment: ' . $job_id . ' instead of only $job_id.

Comment: aah now I saw what you meant. I just pasted the original code. I will edit. Thanks for the observation!

Comment: Thanks and I marked your answer because of the effort u did put but it does not work still I do not knw y . and cau please give the complete aswer as I asked ?